# "Java JDK Installation Issue on Windows 10: 'Java installation is already in process'"

Tags: java, windows, installation, windows-10-universal

I'm facing an issue while attempting to install JDK on my Windows 10 system. I've downloaded the 'JDK 21 x64 installer,' and the download has completed successfully. However, I'm encountering a problem during the installation process. Each time I try to install, a pop-up appears, indicating 'Java installation is already in process. Wait for complete installation and try again.'

I've made several attempts to resolve this issue, including searching for ways to complete the installation or halt the ongoing process. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet. I've also sought assistance from ChatGPT , but to no avail.

"After seeking assistance from ChatGPT multiple times without finding a satisfactory solution, I am now seeking clarification on whether I am downloading the correct version of JDK for my system. Additionally, I would like to know the steps to halt the ongoing installation process.Any guidance or insights into resolving this installation roadblock would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer and tried again?

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted my computer and retried the installation process. However, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there are some files you haven't deleted before trying to install again. try using 'Everything' app or something similar to delete files related to JDK.